Dates in chez-scheme according to the gregorian calendar (< 01.01.1970)
I need to work with dates that contain birth dates. The program must therefore be able to process dates before 1970. Otherwise I would not be able to calculate the age of a person who was born in 1955, for example. My preferred scheme implementation is chez scheme. But i could only find the possibility to work with dates from 01.01.1970.
(make-date 0 0 0 0 1 5 1985) ; -> OK
(make-date 0 0 0 0 1 5 1955) ; ->  Exception in make-date: invalid combination of arguments

Working with dates is so fundamental that I cannot imagine that chez scheme has no built in procedures/data structures for using "gregorian dates". But I can't find them, neither in the manual (csug 10.0.0) nor on the internet.
Can anyone help?

It may work on your case, but there are many other cases which data can fail, so better not to implement things that could get wrong results. Do you really need to know the timezone and the time one person is born? Or what about a person born in a territory with Julian calendar at a time? So do not use over-precisely functions: it give a wrong sense of precision.

Unfortunately, it is very rare to find a sensible date library for pretty much any language. Most, like Chez, make the fundamental mistake of associating a date with a point in time.

These functions are often based on SRFI-19 which has no limit at 1970. I tested Chez Scheme 9.5.8 as packaged for Ubuntu 24.04 and make-date works for older years.
